# What happened to the synagogue in Urmia (Daneshgah-e-Kalimi)?

Tags: synagogue

My family is from Urmia, Iran. They said there was a very old synagogue there, and they have no idea what happened to it, as they left during the revolution. I was wondering if anyone knows anything, as there were Torah scrolls and, according to my family, an 800-year-old Aramit (Aramaic) translation of Megillat Esther. I hope that these were preserved or brought to Israel.

Comment: (There are Jew's living in Iran now,  there is the tomb of mordichiai and Ester https://youtu.be/Wp5DWM3l6OA ), related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urmia

Answer (score 1):

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_synagogues_in_Iran) they claim it is active and being used, their source is a book printed in 2002 (which might have recent photos of it), I guess the Torahs are still there.

you might want to see the book or contact its author for better information